# SQL Server - Create Table script not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, create-table, ssms

Trying to add a table to my database in SQL Server Management Studio but it's throwing a wobbly. I'm sure it's real simple but my brain has gone to mush and I can't find the problem. Basically it's telling me the database already exists, yet it clearly doesn't.

Error(s):

> Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 2
>   Cannot drop the table 'MySchema.mix_Case_Study-Module', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
>   There is already an object named 'mix_Case_Study-Module' in the database.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
>
> Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot find the object "MySchema.mix_Case_Study-Module" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

SQL:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DROP TABLE [MySchema].[mix_Case_Study-Module]

CREATE TABLE [MySchema].[mix_Case_Study-Module](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Case Study ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Module ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Position] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [mix_Case_Study-Module] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [ID] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[mix_Case_Study-Module] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_mix_Case_Study-Module_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]

GO
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: do you have drop permission?

Comment: @VictorRibeirodaSilvaEloy yes

Comment: are you sure about the schema name "[MySchema]"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constraint name and table name are the same.

```
CREATE TABLE [MySchema].[mix_Case_Study-Module]
```

and

```
CONSTRAINT [mix_Case_Study-Module] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: You sir, are a superstar.

Answer (score 0):

You are having issues because you're first trying to drop a table that does not exist.

You should be using something like this:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF OBJECT_ID([MySchema].[mix_Case_Study-Module], 'u') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [MySchema].[mix_Case_Study-Module]

CREATE TABLE [MySchema].[mix_Case_Study-Module](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Case Study ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Module ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Position] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [mix_Case_Study-Module_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [ID] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [MySchema].[mix_Case_Study-Module] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_mix_Case_Study-Module_Active]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]

GO
```